# How to allocate memory to memcached?

Tags: memory, ubuntu-14.04, memcached, bitnami

I need to allocate memory to memcached. 
I executed following command

```
sudo find / -name memcached.conf
```

and it returned a single file located at `/opt/bitnami/common/etc/memcached.conf` and it contains following content

```
mech_list: plain
log_level: 5
sasldb_path: /opt/bitnami/common/etc/sasldb2
```

And

```
ps aux | grep '[m]emcached'
```

gives following output

```
memcach+ 20227  0.0  0.0 329828  1164 ?        Ssl  Jan20   0:00 /opt/bitnami/memcached/bin/.memcached.bin -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11211 -P /opt/bitnami/memcached/tmp/memcached.pid -u memcached -d
```

I don't know how much ram is set as default, I need to allocate more memory to it and set other configs. I've found links which suggest to use option **-m** to allocate memory but I'm seeing any such config files in my system.

Answer (score 2):

By default 64MB is allocated. You can increase it using the `-m` option. For example, to increase it to 128MB add it in the `memcached.conf` as below in a new line and restart memcached:

```
-m 128
```

Check: [Using memcached](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/ha-memcached-using.html) and [Memcached Installation and Configuration with PHP on Debian server](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/install-memcached-php-debian)